# Почему валится код функции дешифрования?

Tags: шифрование, c#

Доброго всем времени суток!
В проекте возникла необходимость шифрования данных. Скачал из интернета код шифрования. повозился с ним. Изрядно изменил...
Когда стал тестировать - заметил что процедура шифрования идеально работает, а вот дефишрования отказывается...

```
    // Процедура дешифрования
    public static string DecryptData(string data)
    {
        MemoryStream memorystream;
        StreamReader streamreader;
        CryptoStream crstream;

        // Определить алгоритм
        SymmetricAlgorithm Alg = DefineAlg();
        ICryptoTransform Cryptor = CreateDec(Alg);

        // Получаем массив байтов
        byte[] bytedata = ToBytes(data);

        memorystream = new MemoryStream(bytedata);
        crstream = new CryptoStream(memorystream, Cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        streamreader = new StreamReader(crstream);

        // Показываем результат
        string decdata = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

        // Закрываем потоки
        crstream.Close();
        streamreader.Close();
        memorystream.Close();

        return decdata;
    }
```

Понять, почему - не могу. Подозрения на

```
            string decdata = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
```

Возможно дело в стриме. При компиляции слетает отсюда, а самое главное, что никаких эксепшенов не выскакивает... Помогите разобраться.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, строка у Вас криво зашифровалась.

Попрбоуйте после завершения шифрования перед закрытием потока, в который происходит шифрование, вызывать CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock().

Проверьте также, что при шифровании Вы сначала закрываете CryptoStream, а потом - поток, в котором происходит шифрование.

Ещё. При работе с потоками рекомендую использовать блок using. Это надёжнее, чем вызов Close после завершения операции, так как гарантирует освобождение ресурсов вне зависимости от возникших исключений.

Comment: Спасибо) плюсую)
А что эта функция делает?

Comment: Этот метод дописывает в поток, на базе которого создан CryptoStream, данные, которые могут потребоваться криптографическому алгоритму при расшифровке.