# Странно работает класс шифрования

Tags: шифрование, c#

Доброго времени суток!
Вопрос по классу, который я пишу на C#
Класс должен шифровать строку и расшифровывать.... Проблемы с ошибками, описанные в  [другом моем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19486/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F4) решены.
Теперь класс работает, однако шифровка и расшифровка происходят довольно странно.
 1. Допустим мы шифруем строку "My Mom Is Very Cool".
 2. В замен получаем "䷓䑾ョ蜻摼ዮ䈱㑴쇅�︉䵚⮊⟠Ⰹ촌".
 3. При расшифровке полученого : "My Mom Is Veᢐ뫛늄눵⟥ol"
 4. При повторной шифровке "䷓䑾ョ蜻摼ዮ䈱㑴쇅�︉䵚⮊⟠Ⰹ촌". (тоже самое что в пункте 2)

Ниже выкладываю код класса целиком

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace OD
{
public class Cryptography
{
    // Ключ и IV для TripleDES
    static byte[] TripleKey = { 77, 79, 156, 172, 12, 40, 96, 226, 93, 78, 90, 103, 186, 78, 117, 0, 85, 127, 114, 91, 148, 210, 242, 255 };
    static byte[] TripleIV = { 19, 127, 43, 85, 21, 117, 80, 151 };

    // Процедура шифрования
    public static string EncryptData(string data)
    {
        // Определяем алгоритм
        SymmetricAlgorithm Alg = DefineAlg();
        ICryptoTransform Cryptor = CreateEnc(Alg);

        // Получаем массив байтов
        byte[] bytedata = ToBytes(data);

        byte[] encbytedata;
        using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(memorystream, Cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // Шифруем
                cryptostream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
                cryptostream.FlushFinalBlock();
                cryptostream.Flush();

                encbytedata = memorystream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();
        return enc.GetString(encbytedata);
    }
    // Процедура дешифрования
    public static string DecryptData(string data)
    {
        // Определить алгоритм
        SymmetricAlgorithm Alg = DefineAlg();
        ICryptoTransform Cryptor = CreateDec(Alg);

        // Получаем массив байтов
        byte[] bytedata = ToBytes(data);

        string decdata;
        using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(bytedata))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(memorystream, Cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (BinaryReader streamreader = new BinaryReader(cryptostream))
                {
                    UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();
                    decdata = enc.GetString(streamreader.ReadBytes(bytedata.Length));
                }
            }
        }

        return decdata;
    }

    // Функция, преобразующая строку в массив байтов
    static byte[] ToBytes(string s)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();
        return enc.GetBytes(s);
    }

    // Функция, возвращающая выбранный алгоритм шифрования
    static SymmetricAlgorithm DefineAlg()
    {
        return new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    // Функция, создающая интерфейс-шифратор
    static ICryptoTransform CreateEnc(SymmetricAlgorithm AlgType)
    {
        return AlgType.CreateEncryptor(TripleKey, TripleIV);
    }
    // Функция, создающая интерфейс-дешифратор
    static ICryptoTransform CreateDec(SymmetricAlgorithm AlgType)
    {
        return AlgType.CreateDecryptor(TripleKey, TripleIV);
    }
}
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста из-за чего вся проблема?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какого чёрта вы прогоняете через string? Это же не правильно. Результатом шифрования строки является набор байтов. Ну так и работайте с байтами. Если надо отобразить, то прогоняйте через BASE64. Наверняка ваши странные "галлюцинации" вызваны отображением байтов в юникод и обратно, при котором данные искажаются.

Comment: Оу... действительно... что это я)) Спасибо большое) плюсую